# How to hide rows in another sheet using button

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide a few rows in another sheet using a button. The intention is to hide the rows when needed using the button so the formatting and contents in those rows are untouched. Currently, I delete those rows which disrupt the formatting and need to rework.

I also have no knowledge of VBA whatsoever so please excuse my ignorance.

```
Sub Macro() 
    Rows("7:9").Select 
    If Rows("7:9").Hidden=True Then 
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden=False 
    Else 
        Selection.EntireRowRow.Hidden=True 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro for the action you want to reproduce?

Comment: Yes, I came across few but not sure how do link the second sheet

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried.

Comment: You need to state which sheet the row you're trying to hide is on.  The MS Docs help page has a good example for hiding a column - is almost exactly the same for a row:  [Range.Hidden Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hidden)

Comment: Sub Macro() Rows("7:9").Select If Rows("7:9").Hidden=True Then Selection.EntireRow.Hidden=False Else Selection.EntireRowRow.Hidden=True End If End Sub

Comment: It would be good if it can be toggle

Answer (score 1):

Your code will hide/unhide the rows on the activesheet.

To do it on a specific sheet you need to state which sheet the rows are on - and you do this *without* selecting the rows meaning you can't use `Selection`.

Syntax also has to be spot on - so `.EntireRowRow` will never work.

In the code I've made use of the [With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) statement to shorten the code.

```
Sub Macro()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("7:9")
        If .Hidden = True Then
            .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            .EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Not using `With` would look like this:

```
Sub Macro()
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("7:9").Hidden = True Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("7:9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("7:9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You shorten the code further by swapping TRUE to FALSE and visa-versa.

```
Sub Macro()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("7:9")
        .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
    End With
End Sub
```

The [Not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference//operators/not-operator) operator will switch boolean TRUE to FALSE and FALSE to TRUE.
`.EntireRow.Hidden` will return TRUE or FALSE so `Not .EntireRow.Hidden` will return the opposite.

If you want a running index of visible rows you can use the [SUBTOTAL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) function to count visible cells that contain a value.
This assumes that all cells in column B contain a value and uses the [COUNTA](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) function of *Subtotal*.
The formula typed into `A2` would be:  `=SUBTOTAL(103, $B$1:$B2)` and dragged down.
**Note** that the second cell reference uses relative referencing for the row number - when dragged down the formula will update to `=SUBTOTAL(103, $B$1:$B3)`... `$B$1:$B4` and so on.  The `103` in the function indicates that hidden cells aren't included in the count.

To add this in the code you'd update to:

```
Sub Macro()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'A2:A & last row
        'OFFSET(,-1) is used so it counts values in column B to find the last row
        'and then references column A for the final range.
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(, -1))
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(103, R1C2:RC2)"
        End With

        With .Rows("7:9")
            .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. Is it possible to update series only the visible rows. After I hide the rows the serial numbers had to updated manually anyway it can automatically determined for visible cells.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "_update series only the visible rows_" or where the serial numbers come in - you haven't mentioned them before.

Comment: I have column with serial numbers, when the rows are hidden the serial numbers are to be changed manually. Anyway these numbers can be determined automatically for the visible cells?

Comment: Do the serial numbers start at one?  Will they go up in steps of one?  So first visible row is serial number 1, second is 2 and so on?

Comment: Yes, it starts with one and goes on.

Comment: I'll add that to my answer.